# How to safely iterate over an IAsyncEnumerable to send a collection downstream for message processing in batches

Tags: c#, .net, collections, iterator, iasyncenumerable

I've watched the chat on [LINQ with IAsyncEnumerable](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Supporting-IAsyncEnumerable-with-LINQ) which has given me some insight on dealing with extension methods for IAsyncEnumerables, but wasn't detailed enough frankly for a real-world application, especially for my experience level, and I understand that samples/documentation don't really exist as of yet for `IAsyncEnumerable`s

I'm trying to read from a file, do some transformation on the stream, returning a `IAsyncEnumerable`, and then send those objects downstream after an arbitrary number of objects have been obtained, like:

```
await foreach (var data in ProcessBlob(downloadedFile))
{
    //todo add data to List<T> called listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements
    if (listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements.Count == preConfiguredNumber)
        await _messageHandler.Handle(listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements);
        
    //repeat the behaviour till all the elements in the IAsyncEnumerable returned by ProcessBlob are sent downstream to the _messageHandler.
}
```

My understanding from reading on the matter so far is that the `await foreach` line is working on data that employs the use of `Task`s (or `ValueTask`s), so we don't have a count up front. I'm also hesitant to use a List variable and just do a length-check on that as sharing that data across threads doesn't seem very thread-safe.

I'm using the `System.Linq.Async` package in the hopes that I could use a relevant extensions method. I can see some promise in the form of `TakeWhile`, but my understanding on how thread-safe the task I intend to do is not all there, causing me to lose confidence.

Any help or push in the right direction would be massively appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `System.Linq.Async` is part of Reactive extensions

Comment: My first Idea would be TPL DataFlow with a [BatchBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-using-batchblock-and-batchedjoinblock-to-improve-efficiency)...

Comment: The samples and docs are there. People think that IAsyncEnumerable is more than it really is though. It's 'just' a way to enumerate asynchronously, not a new way to construct pipelines, or a new way of multi-threading. It's neither a Dataflow block nor a Channel. It can be the glue between steps in a pipeline

Comment: Whether you can use a List<T> or need a ConcurrentQueue<T> depends on how your processing code works, not the source (IAsyncEnumerable), just as it doesn't depend on `IEnumerable<T>`. If you have multiple tasks consuming from the source, you need `ConcurrentQueue`. If you only have one tasks, you can use a `List`, although that will prevent you from ever using multiple tasks. A batch operation doesn't need multiple tasks though

Comment: I suspect you should clean up your code first, convert it to a form that makes creating pipelines easy. Field-level handlers make things a lot harder. It's far easier to work with LINQ-style methods - methods that accept an `IAsyncEnumerable` as parameter and *return* another one. You could chain multiple methods one after the other to create a pipeline, always knowing what each method does, how it handles concurrency etc. A method `IAsyncEnumerable<IList<T>>` Batch<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)` allows `ProcessBlob(downloadedFile).Batch(100)....`

Comment: Just out of experience: Also mind the situation, where your batch isn't full for an extended amount of time ...

Comment: Related: [How to batch an IAsyncEnumerable<T>, enforcing a maximum interval policy between consecutive batches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67661709/how-to-batch-an-iasyncenumerablet-enforcing-a-maximum-interval-policy-between)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm also hesitant to use a List variable and just do a length-check on that as sharing that data across threads doesn't seem very thread-safe.

You need to think in terms of *execution flows*, not threads, when dealing with `async`; since you are `await`-ing the processing step, there isn't actually a concurrency problem accessing the list, because regardless of which threads are used: the list is only accessed once at a time.

If you are *still* concerned, you could `new` a list per batch, but that is probably overkill. What you *do* need, however, is two additions - a reset between batches, and a final processing step:

```cs
var listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements = new List<YourType>(preConfiguredNumber);
await foreach (var data in ProcessBlob(downloadedFile)) // CAF?
{
    listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements.Add(data);
    if (listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements.Count == preConfiguredNumber)
    {
        await _messageHandler.Handle(listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements); // CAF?
        listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements.Clear(); // reset for a new batch
        // (replace this with a "new" if you're still concerned about concurrency)
    }
}
if (listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements.Any())
{   // process any stragglers
    await _messageHandler.Handle(listWithPreConfiguredNumberOfElements); // CAF?
}
```

You might *also* choose to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the three spots marked `// CAF?`

Comment: It was the shift in thinking that settled this for me - somewhat of a paradigm shift and was causing confusion. I'm upvoting this as the solution was obvious but the explanation behind it really took it over the line for me, thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is an operator `Buffer` that does what you want, in the package [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/).

```
// Projects each element of an async-enumerable sequence into consecutive
// non-overlapping buffers which are produced based on element count information.
public static IAsyncEnumerable<IList<TSource>> Buffer<TSource>(
    this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, int count);
```

This package contains operators like `Amb`, `Throw`, `Catch`, `Defer`, `Finally` etc that do not have a direct equivalent in Linq, but they do have an equivalent in [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/). This is because `IAsyncEnumerable`s are conceptually closer to `IObservable`s than to `IEnumerable`s (because both have a time dimension, while `IEnumerable`s are timeless).